# Spark - Combinations without repetition

Tags: scala, apache-spark, combinations, rdd

I am trying to do all lines combinations without repetition of a text file.

Example:

1. 1
2. 2
3. 2
4. 1
5. 1

**Result:**

- Line 1 with line 2 = (1,2)
- Line 1 with line 3 = (1,2)
- Line 1 with line 4 = (1,1)
- Line 1 with line 5 = (1,1)
- Line 2 with line 3 = (2,2)
- Line 2 with line 4 = (2,1)
- Line 2 with line 5 = (2,1)
- Line 3 with line 4 = (2,1)
- Line 3 with line 5 = (2,1)
- Line 4 with line 5 = (1,1)

**or**

Considering (x,y), if (x != y) 0 else 1:

- 0
- 0
- 1
- 1
- 1
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 0
- 1

I have the following code:

```
def processCombinations(rdd: RDD[String]) = {
    rdd.mapPartitions({ partition => {
        var previous: String = null;
        if (partition.hasNext)
          previous = partition.next

        for (element <- partition) yield {
          if (previous == element)
            "1"
          else
            "0"
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

The piece of code above is doing the combinations of the first element of my RDD, in other words: (1,2) (1,2) (1,1) (1,1).

The problem is: This code ONLY works with ONE PARTITION. I'd like to make this work with many partitions, how could I do that?

Comment: Your example has a lot of repeated combinations, which you say you don't want. Also, everything after the bolded **or** is sort of a mystery. Can you please take some time to improve your question?

Comment: @marios, the combinations I want is considering the lines but getting the data.

(1,2) = (1,2)
(1,3) = (1,2)
(1,4) = (1,1) ...

After the bolded or:
if (x != y) 0 else 1

Comment: This looks like it will need a fairly complex aggregate function as this is not exactly an easy to distribute problem due to the requirement to track all state really.

Comment: isn't this just `rdd.cartesian(rdd).distinct()`?

Comment: It isn't rdd.cartesian(rdd).distinct().

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "without repetition". It's not clear. Do you mean that if you have (value-in-row x, value-in-row y), then (value-in-row y, value-in-row x) is a duplicate? And (value-in-row x, value-in-row-x) shouldn't appear?

Comment: Do you mean that if you have (value-in-row x, value-in-row y), then (value-in-row y, value-in-row x) is a duplicate? Yes.
--
And (value-in-row x, value-in-row-x) shouldn't appear? It should not.
--
Exactly what you did below.

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear exactly what you want as output, but this reproduces your first example, and translates directly to Spark. It generates combinations, but only where the index of the first element in the original list is less than the index of the second, which is I think what you're asking for.

```
val r = List(1,2,2,1,1)
val z = r zipWithIndex

z.flatMap(x=>z.map(y=>(x,y))).collect{case(x,y) if x._2 < y._2 => (x._1, y._1)}
//List((1,2), (1,2), (1,1), (1,1), (2,2), (2,1), (2,1), (2,1), (2,1), (1,1))
```

or, as a for-comprehension

```
for (x<-z; y<-z; if x._2 < y._2) yield (x._1, y._1)
```

Comment: It worked! I am learning Spark and Scala.
My aim is to compare these results with another one like:
The combinations of: (2,1,2,1,1) = [(2,1),(2,2),(2,1),(2,1),(1,2),(1,1),(1,1),(2,1),(2,1),(1,1)]

My question is: When I do the repartition of my RDD it doesn't keep the order of my objects shuffling the results. Although if my RDDs have the same size the results are going to match each combination?

Comment: Sorry, don't know anything much about how Spark does repartitioning.

Comment: So is it possible to keep track of each combination?
For example, (1,2) will be always the first combination, (1,2) the second, (1,1) third and so on.

Comment: Not sure what order you mean. But my code adds an index as it calculates, you could just keep that for later processing. However, I'm not sure exactly what you're aiming to do when comparing one with another

Answer (score 0):

This code calculate the combinations without repetitions by using recursion. It gets 2 arguments: number of elements for the combination and the list of elements.

It works in the following way: for the given list: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 => It takes the 4 first elements for the first combination. Then It generates other combination with 5, the last element of the list. When there are not more elements left in the list, It moves one position back (third position) and takes the next element to generates more combinations from there: 1, 2, "4", 5. This operation is done recursively with all of elements of the list.

```scala
def combinator[A](n: Int, list: List[A], acc: List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  if (n == 0)
    List(acc.reverse)
  else if (list == Nil)
    List()
  else
    combinator(n - 1, list.tail, list.head :: acc) ::: combinator(n, list.tail, acc)
}

combinator(4, List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), List()).foreach(println)

// List(1, 2, 3, 4)
// List(1, 2, 3, 5)
// List(1, 2, 4, 5)
// List(1, 3, 4, 5)
// List(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience. Please edit your answer to include [clarification, context and try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)